# structural equation modelling adding a categorical variable with lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

have the data of two tests.
test about engagement evaluated with two sections and 10 questions
6 of them about working engagement A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6
4 of them about intention to leave B1,B2,B3,B4

Moreover, the other test about branding is measured by 3 sections in 12 questions
working environment, with 3 questions C1,C2,C3
work life balance with 4 questions D1,D2,D3,D4
benefits with 3 questions, E1,E2,E3

My objective is analyze the effect of branding in engagement.
I am considering structural equation modelling.

I define the latent variables:
model<- 'working_engagement =~ A1+A2+A3+A4+A5+A6
intention_to_leave =~B1+B2+B3+B4

```
   engagement =~ working engagement + intentiton_to_leave
   environment=~C1+C2+C3
   balance=~D1+D2+D3+D4
   benefits=~E1+E2+E3
   branding=~enfironment+balance+benefits
   ## Regression
    engagement ~ branding + categorical'
```

categorical is an additional variable that says if an individual is part of a group or not.

I have added that additional variable because I want to analyze the effect of branding in engagement based on that categorical variable. I mean for group A or B depending categorical.

Then I called the model fittig by:

```
    fit1 <- cfa(model=model_1,data=data)
    fit_sem1 <- sem(model=model_1,data=data)
```

That are two equivalent ways of solving the problem. But I cant understand the outputs of the regression part.

[![outcome][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWQpC.jpg

Comment: Note: you have a typo here - environment and enfironment presumably. However, please specify this as a question! Not clear what you want to know especially since the output image did not appear.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to analyze the effect of branding in engagement based on that categorical variable. I mean for group A or B depending categorical

It is not entirely clear what you mean.  Here are 2 possibilities:

(1) If you want to *statistically control* for group differences when estimating or testing the effect of `branding`, then your syntax is fine, as long as `categorical` is a numerically coded variable (e.g., a dummy code).

https://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/cat.html

(2) If you want to allow `categorical` to *moderate* the effect of `branding`, you can remove `categorical` from the equation and instead add it as a grouping variable to fit the model separately in each group (i.e., different estimated slopes of `branding` for Group A and Group B):

```
fit1 <- cfa(model=model_1, data=data, group = "categorical")
```